# Angular 4 | creating extra div when *ngIf is triggered

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

Good day, i am doing right here? im calling an API data but when in my **if** condition it seems to create extra div when validating to false.

```
<div *ngFor="let apidata of data">
    <div class="box" *ngIf="apidata.Zone == 8">
      <div class="box-assignmentnumber-holder">
        <span id="AssignmentNumber">{{apidata.Assignment}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="newAssignment">
        <span>{{ apidata.Operator == null ? 'New' : apidata.Operator }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

what would be the best approach here to eliminate the extra div in my code?

example result below..

```
<div></div> <---extra div when false
<div></div> <---extra div when false
<div class="box">
     <div class="box-assignmentnumber-holder">
          <span>123123</span>
     </div>
</div>
<div></div> <---extra div when false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is replace `div` with `ng-container` of `*ngFor` :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let apidata of data">
    <div class="box" *ngIf="apidata.Zone == 8">
        <div class="box-assignmentnumber-holder">
            <span id="AssignmentNumber">{{apidata.Assignment}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="newAssignment">
            <span>{{ apidata.Operator == null ? 'New' : apidata.Operator }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<ng-container>
```

This will not create extra `divs` if condition is `false`.

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-extra-div-issue)**

Comment: i try this one but still create extra div. i think my problem is in my loop.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `ng-container` instead of div

> In order to avoid having to create that extra div, we can instead use
>   ng-container directive:

```
ng-container *ngIf="lessons">
    <div class="lesson" *ngFor="let lesson of lessons">
        <div class="lesson-detail">
            {{lesson | json}}
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

> As we can see, the ng-container directive provides us with an element
>   that we can attach a structural directive to a section of the page,
>   without having to create an extra element just for that.
>
> There is another major use case for the ng-container directive: it can
>   also provide a placeholder for injecting a template dynamically into
>   the page.

Reference - https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: this is what im looking for, but what if the data i want to validate is inside the API object? should i do <ng-container *ngIf="lessons.testme"></ng-container> ??

Comment: Yes, it will be great if you can replicate this issue in stackblitz or else you can try

Comment: but its not working in my end, i try to put mg if condition in ng-container but its not working. because i need to loop first my api data to be able to access the object on it.

Comment: @JydonMah can you you replicate this in stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your condition is true or false you'll always have a div created because of the loop

```
<div *ngFor="let apidata of data">
```

Try This

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let apidata of data">
    <div class="box" *ngIf="apidata.Zone == 8">
        <div class="box-assignmentnumber-holder">
           <span id="AssignmentNumber">{{apidata.Assignment}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="newAssignment">
           <span>{{ apidata.Operator == null ? 'New' : apidata.Operator }}
           </span>
        </div>
    </div>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: this wont work, i already try this one but it didnt work out.